# Running Program on Different Linux Distros

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, binaryfiles

I have this program 'prog' that I can run with no problem on my server. When attempting to run it on my own machine (64-bit Ubuntu), I get the message:

```
 bash: ./prog: cannot execute binary file
```

I've made sure all the permissions for all files involved are set to 777 just to be sure it's not a permissions issue. I believe the server is 32-bit, which may be the reason. However, shouldn't the 64-bit os be able to run a 32-bit program since it's just a subset of architectures? If not, is there some emulator I can download for Ubuntu that will allow me to run 32-bit programs if that is indeed the problem?

I understand the 'cannot execute binary file' error is somewhat encompassing, so the above is just my guess at why I'm getting the message, but perhaps someone else has another theory?

Thanks again all.

Comment: what does the output of the "file" command on your file says ? (file prog)

Comment: I get the following output: 

`prog: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xaa50c47441bf86304c5d2b6cf58e69ca36460d1f, not stripped`

Comment: You may not have a 32-bit ld installed.  You'll also need to install 32-bit versions of any libraries it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the 32-bit (shared) libraries used by `prog` on your 64-bit computer. Otherwise `prog` cannot get executed.

Try to install them using

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

(if `prog` requires even more libraries, also install their 32-bit versions)

This should do the trick.

**Note** that if you have the source of `prog`, it might be more convenient (less installing of 32 bit libraries) to recompile `prog` on your 64-bit computer.

Comment: Hey Veger, attempted to `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`, but I got the following message 
`Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`
Is it called something else? Is this an older name for this package by chance? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: In Ubuntu precise it is [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ia32-libs), in fact I have it installed on my machine. You can also try the `ia32-libs-multiarch` it should install the same 32-bit libraries. There is also an [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#How_to_Make_32-bit_Applications_Work_on_a_64-bit_Operating_System) on this topic.